# Парсинг с помощью xpath. Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Здравствуйте! Как с помощью xpath задать путь до нескольких конкретных элементов, т.е у меня есть, к примеру такой код:

```html
<div id="post-body">

<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<blockquote><p>blockquote/p1</p></blockquote>
<div><p>div/p1</p></div>
 <blockquote><p>blockquote/p2</p></blockquote>
  </div>
```

Мне нужно вытащить:

```
p1
p2
blockquote/p1
blockquote/p2
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177017/xpath-get-nodes-that-do-not-have-an-x-ancestor

Comment: могу предложить вытащить элементы с post-body  //Employee[@id='post-body']

Comment: К примеру так `/div[@id="post-body"]/p/text() | /div[@id="post-body"]/blockquote/p/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в данном случае, проще всего будет искать дочерние р элементы к id="post-body" будет так: `id('post-body')/p/text() | id('post-body')//blockquote/p/text()`